# How to print documents in HTML5

Tags: html, silverlight-5.0

Can anyone tell how to print custom documents with HTML5?
This is what i want with this print function. 
I have document management system that already have print function build using silverlight. I want a solution to replace silverlight plugin from HTML5. please give me any idea or a solution.

Comment: do you mean print, as in with ink on paper using a physical printer? or are you trying to convert arbitrary documents into HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are already displaying the document in the webpage using `Iframe`,

If the assumption is correct, you can print the content of the `iframe` as following code

```
<input type="button" onclick="printIframe()" value="print" />

<iframe id="printf" name="printf" src="./sample.pdf"></iframe>

<script>
    function printIframe() {
        var target = document.getElementById('printf');
        try {
            target.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
        } catch (e) {
            target.contentWindow.print();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or else if you are not using `Iframe`, just write a custom print css file to display only the content of the document you want to print.

**Note: You don't have direct access to the printer using javascript**

Comment: thank you for your idea. this was help full me for documents that have one page. if my pdf have more than one page what can be the solution?

Comment: This work for any number of pages. this will open the browser print dialog and you can print all pages, range of pages or given page by changing the `pages` option of the print dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the style of what HTML5 looks like when it is printed with css @media print rules. For instance if you wanted to make the font-size larger when printed you would do,

```
p{
   font-size: 15px
}
@media print {
    p{
    font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp